# How to fix cordova run android --device deploy if no devices found

Tags: android, cordova, adb

The command stop working `cordova run android --device` on mackbook giving me error:

> Error: Failed to deploy to device, no devices found.

Struggling a lot with it. Any other way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went away to usb and did it wirelessly ,  [I found a suggestion this 
 in this site](http://rabryant.blogspot.com.br/2015/03/airdroid.html)

So you have to:

- Install on your android https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid
- Access via browser [airdroid](http://web.airdroid.com/)
- build your debug apk `cordova build android --device --release`
- go to http://web.airdroid.com/
- upload to your mobile
- install it

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I had to:

1. Enable the **Developer Options** on my Android Phone
2. Under Developer Options:
   turn on '*USB Debugging*' and also turn off '*Verify apps over USB*'

To enable Developer Options, go to your phone's settings. Then Enter the "About" submenu. Click the "Model Number" multiple times until your phone asks you to confirm if you would like to enable Developer Options.

Answer (score 2):

here are few tips:

- Try adb devices
- If you are able to see the device, try adb tcpip 5555 (if successful, you should see a confirmation message).
- Then, you need to connect to your device(assuming it is on same network) by using adb connect :5555

vola!! that's it.

Most common problems i encountered with device connection:

- In windows, sometimes the device drivers may get corrupted, so try re-installing/pointing the driver to any other Android device driver(most of them are compatible).
- Make sure your Android SDK is up to date and pointing to correct ANDROID_HOME path.
- Most importantly make sure your device is responding to adb commands by connecting to other computer if you can...